# How do I read bytes from a file into strings and ints using C?

Tags: c, file, io, fwrite, fread

I wrote a file using C's `fwrite` where I wrote a string, followed by some ints, multiple times. I used this code to write:

```
fwrite(&words,sizeof(char),strlen(words) - 1, outputFile);
fwrite(&nextNum,sizeof(int),1, outputFile);
```

How can I read my file back into strings and ints?

Also, would it be faster to read an array of ints from the file instead of multiple consecutive ints?

Comment: 1. Use `fread` with the same parameters. (You need to know the string length ahead of time.) 2. Yes, much faster.

Comment: By the way, `strlen(words) - 1` is probably a mistake, unless you really do not want to write the last character.

Comment: @DYZ I can't get the string length ahead of time. What if I wrote the length of the string as an int right before the string? And would that work the same with my array of ints?

Comment: Yes, you can write the length of the string before the string, this is actually a common practice. And you can write the length of the array, too.

Comment: @DYZ I'm trying to do this, but when I call `fread` on my char*, it turns into just an empty string.

Comment: @DYZ My code's like this: `fread(&strLength, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&word, sizeof(char), strLength, f);`

Comment: First, have you allocated memory for the string? Second, have you null-terminated the characters after you read the string?

Comment: I changed my code to this: `fread(&strLength, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        char* word = (char*) malloc(strLength*sizeof(char));
        fread(&word, sizeof(char), strLength, f);` so that now I am allocating memory for the string. Now my word is just "\0"

How do I null terminate the characters after I finish the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you write into the file you lose a critical piece of information: the length of your string. There are generally three ways to handle this:

1. (The least efficient!) Assume your strings are shorter than, say, 10 characters and always write 10 characters (padding with spaces as needed) and read back 10 characters, trimming the spaces. This is the "fixed-width" format.
2. Prepend every string you write with the length information, say a 16-bit word (so you limit the size of your strings to 64K, which is adequate for most applications)
3. Use an *end-of-string* indicator. The most obvious one being a `'\0'` null-terminator used for standard C-strings

Of course, reading back would depend on the technique you chose to write the strings out. But once you are done with the string's variable length complication writing/reading integers (which are always of an exact, known size) should be a breeze.

Comment: How would I read back the string using 3) the end of string indicator?

Comment: You read them back either one character at a time (yes, inefficient) or in some-size blocks (say 64 bytes?) and scanning through that block for the *end-of-string* indicator, then concatenating those string pieces together to form the actual read string. In case you read in blocks be sure to "rewind" the file read position back to where the string terminator was though so that you can continue with you read of the integers.

Comment: Having said the above I think you would greatly benefit from the use of `mmap()`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap